# Listening to the Aloha Editor "aloha-smart-content-changed" Event?

Tags: javascript, events, aloha-editor

Accoriding to the Aloha Editor docs you can listen for the "aloha-smart-content-changed" event for help in, say, saving the data to whatever persistence mechanism you are using. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aloha Event Testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/current/lib/aloha.js" data-aloha-plugins="common/format, common/list, common/link, common/highlighteditables"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/current/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Aloha.ready( function() {
        var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
        $('.editable').aloha();
      });
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editable').bind('aloha-smart-content-changed', function() {
          console.log('Aloha smart event handled.');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="editable"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the handler never fires. Would anyone that has worked with Aloha know how to properly listen for the event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, the documenation on this was quite poor. But i think i got it to work. It looks like you bind the event handlers inside the Aloha.ready() method and to the Aloha object itself.

```
Aloha.ready( function() {
        var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
        $('.editable').aloha();

    Aloha.bind('aloha-smart-content-changed', function(event, editable) {
          console.log('Aloha smart event handled.');
        });        
});
```

Found a little bit more info about it [here](http://aloha-editor.org/builds/development/alohaeditor-0.21.0-dev-SNAPSHOT-source-20120330-012607/doc/guides/source/events.textile) and this is where i found an example of an [event being bound](https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/445).

Also tested this in **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rrn8x/3/)**

Hope that helps

Comment: any idea on how to get the actual content? :/

Comment: @Populus Try `Aloha.getActiveEditable().getContents();`.

Comment: Why are they actually wrapping jQuery? Being able to bind Aloha events intuitively as the OP tried seems much much much much nicer. ;-)

Comment: @Populus also try using the second argument, editable.editable.getContents();