# Grabbing Edits from two strings

Tags: javascript, file, storage, edit, safari-extension

**I'm going to go a bit in-depth with my problem, you can jump to the TL;DR if you don't want to read all of this**

## What I'm trying to do

I need to store a "file" *(text document)* which can be user-edited. If I have my original file *(which could be huge)*

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

and the user were to make a change:

> Foo ipsum amet_ sit

Basically, I have the original string and the user-edited string. I want to find the differences, *"edits"*. To prevent storing duplicates of *very large* strings. I want to store the original and the "edits". Then apply the edits to the original. Kind of like data de-duplication. The problem is that I have no idea how different edits can be and I also need to be able to apply those edits to the string.

## Attempts

Because the text could be huge, I am wondering what would be the most "efficient" way to store edits to the text without storing two separate versions. My first guess was something along the lines of:

```
var str = 'Original String of text...'.split(' ') || [],
    mod = 'Modified String of text...'.split(' ') || [], i, edits = [];

for (i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    edits.push(str[i]===mod[i] ? undefined : mod[i]);
}

console.log(edits); // ["Modified", null, null, null] (desired output)
```

then to revert back:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    str[i] = edits[i] || str[i];
}
str.join(' '); // "Modified String of text..."
```

> Basically, I'm trying to split the text by spaces into arrays. Compare the arrays and store the differences. Then apply the differences to generate the modified version

## Problems

But if the amount of spaces were to change, problems would occur:

**`str`**: `Original String of text...`
**`mod`**: `OriginalString of text...`

Output: `OriginalString of text... text...`

My desired output: `OriginalString of text...`

---

Even if  I were to switch `str.length` with `mod.length` and `edits.length` like:

```
// Get edits
var str = 'Original String of text...'.split(' ') || [],
    mod = 'Modified String of text...'.split(' ') || [], i, edits = [];

for (i = 0; i < mod.length; i += 1) {
    edits.push(str[i]===mod[i] ? undefined : mod[i]);
}

// Apply edits
var final = [];
for (i = 0; i < edits.length; i += 1) {
    final[i] = edits[i] || str[i];
}
final = final.join(' ');
```

`edits` would be: `["ModifiedString", "of", "text..."]` in result making the whole 'storing edits thing useless. And even worse if a word were to be added / removed. If `str` were to become `Original String of lots of text...`. The output would still be the same.

---

I can see that they're many flaws in the way I'm doing this, but I can't think of any other way.

**Snippet:**

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById('a').value.split(' ') || [],
    mod = document.getElementById('b').value.split(' ') || [],
    i, edits = [];

  for (i = 0; i < mod.length; i += 1) {
    edits.push(str[i] === mod[i] ? undefined : mod[i]);
  }

  // Apply edits
  var final = [];
  for (i = 0; i < edits.length; i += 1) {
    final[i] = edits[i] || str[i];
  }
  final = final.join(' ');
  alert(final);
};

document.getElementById('go2').onclick = function() {
  var str = document.getElementById('a').value.split(' ') || [],
    mod = document.getElementById('b').value.split(' ') || [],
    i, edits = [];

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    edits.push(str[i] === mod[i] ? undefined : mod[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    str[i] = edits[i] || str[i];
  }
  alert(str.join(' ')); // "Modified String of text..."
};
```

```html
Base String:
<input id="a">
<br/>Modified String:
<input id="b" />
<br/>
<button id="go">Second method</button>
<button id="go2">First Method</button>
```

## TL;DR:

How would you find the changes between two strings?

---

**I'm dealing with large pieces of text each could be about a <s>megabyte</s> hundred kilobytes. This is running on the browser**

Comment: What OS are you using? Is this browser or general (server-side) JavaScript? Is node.js available?

Comment: @orb nope, this is client-side javascript.

Comment: @vihan1086 why do you need this. You are storing original and then replacing original with edits. So why not just replace the original with user edited text. In the end you end up with same results. A text that was modified by user. Why do you need to have edits saved out somewhere. Especially when original is going to be destroyed anyway.

Comment: For example, Original text: `today was a good day`. User edited: `today was a OK day`. (now you want to) save; `-good +OK` and then apply to original text `today was a good day` to `today was a OK day`. Now you have full text: `today was a OK day`, and '-good +OK' edit saved. So i'm asking why? to go back in history?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I do need to be using both the original and the modified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a proper diff using just JavaScript can be potentially slow, but it depends on the performance requirements and the quality of the diff, and of course how often it must be run.

One quite efficient way would be to track the edits when the user is actually editing the document and only store those changes just after the moment they are done. For this you can use for example ACE editor, or any other editor that supports change tracking.

http://ace.c9.io/

ACE is tracking the changes while the document is edited. The ACE editor tracks the commands in easily comprehensible format like:

```
{"action":"insertText","range":{"start":{"row":0,"column":0},
    "end":{"row":0,"column":1}},"text":"d"}
```

You can hook to the changes of the ACE editor and listen to the change events:

```
var changeList = []; // list of changes
// editor is here the ACE editor instance for example
var editor = ace.edit(document.getElementById("editorDivId"));
editor.setValue("original text contents");
editor.on("change", function(e) {
    // e.data has the change
    var cmd = e.data;
    var range = cmd.range;
    if(cmd.action=="insertText") {
        changeList.push([
            1, 
            range.start.row,
            range.start.column,
            range.end.row,
            range.end.column,
            cmd.text
        ])
    }
    if(cmd.action=="removeText") {
        changeList.push([
                2, 
                range.start.row,
                range.start.column,
                range.end.row,
                range.end.column,
                cmd.text
            ])
    }
    if(cmd.action=="insertLines") {
        changeList.push([
                3, 
                range.start.row,
                range.start.column,
                range.end.row,
                range.end.column,
                cmd.lines
            ])
    }
    if(cmd.action=="removeLines") {
        changeList.push([
                4, 
                range.start.row,
                range.start.column,
                range.end.row,
                range.end.column,
                cmd.lines,
                cmd.nl
            ])
    }
});
```

To learn how it works just create some test runs which capture the changes. Basicly there are only those for commands:

1. insertText
2. removeText
3. insertLines
4. removeLines

Removing the newline from the text can be a bit tricky.

When you have this list of changes you are ready to replay the changes against the text file. You can even merge similar or overlapping changes into a single change - for example inserts to subsequent characters could be merged into a single change.

There will be some problems when you are testing this, composing the string back to text is not trivial but quite doable and should not be more than around 100 lines of code or so.

The nice thing is that when you are finished, you have also *undo* and *redo* commands easily available, so you can replay the whole editing process.

Comment: If you have problems, please tell me, I'm also working on this subject and might create some test cases for ACE or some other editor in GitHub too

Comment: The reason I placed to commands inside Array in the Example was that I wanted to have a format which would be less verbose, when sending it over network

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to be using [Aloha Editor](http://www.alohaeditor.org/docs/#multiple-editables) but I'll see what I can do using your answer

Comment: @vihan1086 if you can provide example of how to do something similar with Aloha I might be also interested to know...

Comment: this has some info... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302385/listening-to-the-aloha-editor-aloha-smart-content-changed-event

Comment: that seems exactly what I need, I'll mark this as accepted and I'll later decide who to award the bounty too :)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: Added modified script that can handle more than one text area.**

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqnwp459/1/) for a page with more than one editable text area. (Don't forget to open dev tools to see the edits.) You just need to assign each textarea a unique id. Then, create a map using those id's as keys and each textarea's edits array as the values. Here is the updated script:

```
'use strict';

function Edit(type, position, text) {
  this.type = type;
  this.position = position;
  this.text = text;
}

var ADD = 'add';
var DELETE = 'delete';

var textAreaEditsMap = {};

var cursorStart = -1;
var cursorEnd = -1;
var currentEdit = null;
var deleteOffset = 1;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var textareas = document.getElementsByClassName('text-editable');

  for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; ++i) {
    var textarea = textareas.item(i);
    var id = textarea.getAttribute('id');

    textAreaEditsMap[id] = [];
    textarea.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    textarea.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    textarea.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
  }
});

function handleMouseUp(event) {
  cursorStart = this.selectionStart;
  cursorEnd = this.selectionEnd;
  currentEdit = null;
}

function handleKeyDown(event) {

  cursorStart = this.selectionStart;
  cursorEnd = this.selectionEnd;

  if (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 40) { // detect cursor movement keys
    currentEdit = null;
  }

  // deleting text
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
    if (currentEdit != null && currentEdit.type !== 'delete') {
      currentEdit = null;
    }

    if (cursorStart !== cursorEnd) { // Deleting highlighted text
      var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, this.innerHTML.substring(cursorStart, cursorEnd));
      textAreaEditsMap[this.getAttribute('id')].push(edit);
      currentEdit = null;

    } else if (event.keyCode === 8) { // backspace
      if (currentEdit == null) {
        deleteOffset = 1;
        var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, this.innerHTML[cursorStart - 1]);
        textAreaEditsMap[this.getAttribute('id')].push(edit);
        currentEdit = edit;
      } else {
        ++deleteOffset;
        currentEdit.text = this.innerHTML[cursorStart - 1] + currentEdit.text;
      }

    } else if (event.keyCode === 46) { // delete
      if (currentEdit == null) {
        deleteOffset = 1;
        var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, this.innerHTML[cursorStart]);
        textAreaEditsMap[this.getAttribute('id')].push(edit);
        currentEdit = edit;

      } else {
        currentEdit.text += this.innerHTML[cursorStart + deleteOffset++];
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(textAreaEditsMap)
}

function handleKeyPress(event) {

  if (currentEdit != null && currentEdit.type !== 'add') {
    currentEdit = null;
  }

  if (currentEdit == null) {
    currentEdit = new Edit(ADD, cursorStart, String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
    textAreaEditsMap[this.getAttribute('id')].push(currentEdit);
  } else {
    currentEdit.text += String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
  }

  console.log(textAreaEditsMap);
}
```

**Original post with original script that only handles one textarea follows:**

I made an example script that does what you need. I put a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/5w6fhp8c/2/) on JSFiddle. Make sure you press ctrl+shift+J on the JSFiddle example page to open dev tools so you can see the array of edits logged as edits are made. Edits are added to the edits array in chronological order, so you can revert back to the original text by applying the inverse (i.e., add deleted text back; remove added text) in reverse chronological order (i.e., iterate the array backwards). I did not handle copying, pasting, undoing, or redoing from the context menu or through key bindings, but I think that you should be able to use this example as a guide to take care of those things. Here is the script:

```
'use strict';

function Edit(type, position, text) {
  this.type = type;
  this.position = position;
  this.text = text;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var ADD = 'add';
  var DELETE = 'delete';

  var cursorStart = -1;
  var cursorEnd = -1;
  var edits = [];
  var currentEdit = null;
  var deleteOffset = 1;

  var textarea = document.getElementById('saved-text');

  textarea.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
    cursorStart = this.selectionStart;
    cursorEnd = this.selectionEnd;
    currentEdit = null;
  });

  textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

    cursorStart = this.selectionStart;
    cursorEnd = this.selectionEnd;

    if(event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 40) { // detect cursor movement keys
      currentEdit = null;
    }

    // deleting text
    if(event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
      if(currentEdit != null && currentEdit.type !== 'delete') {
        currentEdit = null;
      }

      if(cursorStart !== cursorEnd) {
        var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, textarea.innerHTML.substring(cursorStart, cursorEnd));
        edits.push(edit);
        currentEdit = null;

      } else if (event.keyCode === 8) { // backspace
        if (currentEdit == null) {
          deleteOffset = 1;
          var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, textarea.innerHTML[cursorStart - 1]);
          edits.push(edit);
          currentEdit = edit;
        } else {
          ++deleteOffset;
          currentEdit.text = textarea.innerHTML[cursorStart - 1] + currentEdit.text;
        }

      } else if (event.keyCode === 46) { // delete
        if(currentEdit == null) {
          deleteOffset = 1;
          var edit = new Edit(DELETE, cursorStart, textarea.innerHTML[cursorStart]);
          edits.push(edit);
          currentEdit = edit;

        } else {
          currentEdit.text += textarea.innerHTML[cursorStart + deleteOffset++];
        }
      }
    }

    console.log(edits)
  });

  textarea.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {

    if(currentEdit != null && currentEdit.type !== 'add') {
      currentEdit = null;
    }

    // adding text
    if(currentEdit == null) {
      currentEdit = new Edit(ADD, cursorStart, String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
      edits.push(currentEdit);
    } else {
      currentEdit.text += String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    }

    console.log(edits);
  });

});
```

Comment: Interesting… How would I apply this to two strings though? I do have a large `contentEditable` area which the edits are made. The problem is, when I get the `innerHTML` will the position be incorrect because it own't include the tags

Comment: Above I modified the script to handle more than one editable text area. Enjoy!

Comment: That seems pretty cool, I'll see if I can integrate this and I'll get back to you

Comment: Quite interesting answer - a pure JS solution to the problem! I proposed something similar using the ACE but I really like this solution, because it does not require external modules

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem akin to code versioning and saving only the changes between versions.

Take a look at [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff)

You can create a patch, save it, and apply it later to the original text to get the modified text.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create basic comparison identifiers, e.g., at `js` below `"+"`, `"-"` ; utilize `.map()` to compare original `o` , edited `e` input strings , return array `diff` of differences between `o` , `e` ; set `o`, `e,` , `diff` as properties of object

```js
var o = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  e = "Foo ipsum amet_ sit"
, res = {
  "original": o,
  "edited": e,
  "diff": o.split("").map(function(val, key) {
    // log edits 
    // `+` preceding character: added character ,
    // `-`: preceding character: removed character;
    // `+` preceding "|": no changes ,
    // `-`: preceding "": no changes;
    // `"index"`: character `index` of original `o` input string
    return e[key] !== val 
           ? "[edits:" + "+" + (e[key] || "") + "|-" + val 
             + ", index:" + key + "]" + (e[key] || "") 
           : "[edits:+|-, index:" + key + "]" + val
  })
};

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: @vihan1086 _"This dif is adding for every item in the array. It'd be shorter to store the two seperate edits"_ Not certain interpret "adding for every item in the array" correctly ? Appear to be only one edit, one original string ?

Comment: @vihan1086 `diff` array does not add for "every character in the string" . Where no changes made between `original` and `edited`  , for example at index `1` , results would be `"[edits:+|-, index:1]o"`; that is, no character appear after `+` , no  character appears after `-`. As indicated at explanation of approach , perhaps most important portion of pattern for maintenance is defining which symbols to utilize to distinguish edits, non-edits. The space character may be challenging to distinguish , as an actual space character is displayed where edited ; e.g. index 3 `"[edits:+ |-e, index:3] "`